I am using KDE, and the equal sign ("=") is auto-typed at random intervals
I am using KDE, running the current version of Debian.
Every so often, the equal sign "=" will be typed into the current application. This sometimes happens after a long interval, and sometimes in short succession. It has proven difficult to reproduce: but if a text editor is left open for several hours or overnight, it will collect anywhere from 1 to 4 of them. Nothing else ever happens.
Now, I suspect this happened shortly after installing Vino server and XRDP, since it never happened when there were no remote connections to the computer. (The computer in question is not accessible to the public internet, only a private home network. I do not think this is the result of any funny business.)
I do not think this is related to the physical keyboard (and yes, I have shaken out all the crumbs).
What sort of mechanisms could cause this behaviour? It is nearly impossible to find information about this online, since other similar problems are legit keyboard issues in Linux -- of which, there are many.

You may have shaken out the crumbs, but have you actually tested this with a different keyboard?
